# Prevent "Exit" command in script to close Cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a .bat which emits "`Exit 1`" in case of failure, this is closing the cmd window and prevents user to see the details of error.

I would like to force cmd to stay opened to see the messages.

I know that I could have used `EXIT /B 1` in .bat to not close the cmd automatically, but only interrupt the script.

> ```
> /B        When used in a batch script, this option will exit 
>           only the script (or subroutine) but not CMD.EXE
>           If executed on the command-line it will close CMD.exe
> ```

But the .bat is generated by a tool, so I can't simply modify it. Obviously, for the same reason I can't just add "PAUSE" in it.

I also know about "cmd /k" which avoids to close cmd after to have run a script, but it just keeps the cmd open once a script is successfully executed, if an "EXIT" function is emitted, it does not prevent cmd to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CMD calls the batch with another `CMD /C xyz.bat` then the `exit 1` inside the bat file should not close the original CMD window, and the `/C` ensures that sub-CMD will close itself at the end of the BAT file if no `exit` was reached.

Then you can check error level for the batch and deal with whatever action you want in the top level CMD - such as `timeout /t 10 && exit` if you want that to close after giving user time to read the error message:

```
cmd /c a.bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (echo ERROR && timeout /t 10 && exit)
```

Comment: CMD /C xyz.bat works perfectly ! Thanks a lot for this trick :).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
if not defined !var! (
  echo Source folder missing^^!
  goto :eof
)
```

Exits the batch file but does not exit CMD. The same as batch `functions` are made.

Comment: Hello, it looks like a change to do in the batch itself. Like I said in first post, it's not an option because the .bat is generated by a tool. Running the batch itself with cmd /C like suggested previously worked very well. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ahh.. This is the case then. Didn't notice ;) gg.

Comment: No problem my friend :)